# How to output in C++ arrays of bytes to binary files without memory leakage?

Tags: c++, memory, binary

I have the task to write a binary file in C++, that is a message with some scientific parameters in it, in the form of metadata (header) and science data (body). After some search, trials and errors how to do that, I decided to use a structure of char arrays and *strcpy* into them the hexadecimal number representation of the bits.

The thing is that, while this worked in some computers, where I tested it, on others it gave me memory related errors. The latest is:

> *** Error in `./WriteBinary.exe': corrupted size vs. prev_size: 0x0000000001189e50 ***

The code below would only show my inexperience with memory management. The question is, where I did wrong in dealing with memory, and what is the correct way to write single byte values to binary files?

```
// housekeeping TM structure
// the PreHeader structure
struct PreHeader {
    char prehead1[4] ;
    char prehead2[2] ;
    char prehead3[2] ;
    char prehead4[3] ;
    char prehead5[1] ;
    char prehead6[5] ;
    char prehead7[1] ;
}
;
// the Header structure
struct Header {
    char head1[4] ;
    char head2[1] ;
    char head3[1] ;
} ;
// the Body structure
struct Body {
    char bd1[61] ;
} ;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

int filenum = atoi(argv[3]);    // a variable to keep the file number
srand(time(NULL) + filenum);  // give a new random set at the present time + offset with the file number for different array generation
char* fileName = argv[1];   // the second argument [1] of the main function is the file name passed by the bash shell script

// setup the file to redirect the output to
ofstream outputFile;
outputFile.open(fileName,ios::binary);

// set the number of telemetry packets
size_t num_tm = atoi(argv[2]);  // number of telemetry packets to be written to the same file

// structures instances
vector<PreHeader> HK_PreHead(num_tm) ;
vector<Header> HK_Head(num_tm) ;
vector<Body> HK_Bd(num_tm) ;

// cycle through the telemetry packets
for ( int i=0; i<num_tm; i++ ) {
    // assign the PreHeader (constant for now)
    strcpy( HK_PreHead[i].prehead1, "\x55\x35\xF8\xA3" );
    strcpy( HK_PreHead[i].prehead2, "\x00\x00" );
    strcpy( HK_PreHead[i].prehead3, "\x97\x26" );
    strcpy( HK_PreHead[i].prehead4, "\x00\x00\x00" );
    strcpy( HK_PreHead[i].prehead5, "\x44" );
    strcpy( HK_PreHead[i].prehead6, "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" );
    strcpy( HK_PreHead[i].prehead7, "\x01" );
    outputFile.write (reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&HK_PreHead[i]),sizeof(HK_PreHead[i]));    // outputs the PreHeader to the file
    // assign the Header (constant for now)
    strcpy( HK_Head[i].head1, "\xE\x44\xC0\x22" );
    strcpy( HK_Head[i].head2, "\x00" );
    strcpy( HK_Head[i].head3, "\x3D" );
    // assign the Body (constant for now)
    outputFile.write (reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&HK_Head[i]),sizeof(HK_Head[i]));    // outputs the Header to the file
    for ( int j=0; j< sizeof(HK_Bd[i]); j++ ) {
        HK_Bd[i].bd1[j] = 0x11 ;
    }
    outputFile.write (reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&HK_Bd[i]),sizeof(HK_Bd[i]));    // outputs the Body to the file
}

outputFile.close();

return 0;}
```

Comment: You can't use strcpy here as it adds a null terminator which overflows your arrays, you'll need to use memcpy or a different method to assign it.

Comment: Why not just write the values directly to the file? Why use the vectors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C reading/writing to a file in binary mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18293482/c-reading-writing-to-a-file-in-binary-mode)

Comment: @DavidMunoz This is not at all a dupe of that.

Comment: @RetiredNinja : That is an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @RetiredNinja In fact, this solved my problem. Thank you! Unfortunately, I still lack the reputation to upvote, but will do so soon :)

Comment: @NeilButterworth I thought maybe I could use the values later in my exercise with telemetry. Probably, I could change it, if there is need for performance.